# Scaling only the selected vertex group in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can scale the top of an object by selecting it's vertex group and hitting 'S'

[image: img1]

When I try and scale a vertex group in Geometry nodes it seems to scale the entire object instead of just the selected vertex group.

I have my selection set to the vertex group I want.

[image: img0]

**I've tried uniform**
[image: img2]

**and single axis**

[image: img3]

I've also tried using offset in this link
[Adjusting / controlling / moving an objects vertex groups using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251626/adjusting-controlling-moving-an-objects-vertex-groups-using-geometry-nodes)

Still the scaling is not limiting itself to the selected vertex group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling is possible with `Scale Elements` only with *Faces* and *Edges* (strangely enough).

So you would have to translate your vertex group to the right domain somehow.

You can do this by simply adding the `Capture Attribute` and set it to *Point*.

This captures the selection on a specific domain, which is then interpreted correctly by `Scale Elements` in the *Face* domain.

[image]

PS: `Named Attribute` is available since **Blender 3.2**.
*(If you use a lower version, you use the `Group Input` instead as usual).*

Comment: Thanks, Not sure why the Scale Elements doesn't have the points / vertices option either (must've been an oversight.  I'll put in a request to have it added).  Thanks for the Named Attribute heads up.  My first time using them and it seems pretty useful.

Comment: Added it as a suggestion.

https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/ojXK/