# Instance a Procedural Amount of Curve Lines which Start and End Point that is Set by Multiple Points possibly using index

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I have this rows of points called "start' and "end". From the "start" group I want to instance a Curve Line whose start point uses index 1 and another Curve Line who uses index 2 and so on with the other Curve Line that will be instanced on this group. After this Curve Lines are instanced on the "start" group, I want its End points to be located on the points of the "end" group.

My problem in here is I can do that but with only one Curve Line. I want to make sure I can create limitless amount of Curve Lines which start and end points are located to this limitless amount of "start" and "end" points.

Image 1: Me struggling to connect a curve line to this points procedurally

[image]

Image 2: nodes

[image]

Comment: Why are you actually asking the same question twice in different ways? You could have edited your original question as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269888/

Comment: sorry about that. I had thought that I should make a question detached from the other one.

Comment: That's OK, but the people working on answering the questions here are trying to keep the information compact. Basically, this question is just a variation of your original problem, but technically identical. If the questions are tweaked so long that a really clear answer can be given, it will increase the usefulness for visitors who have similar problems. Maybe it would be good if you try to specify your question again, so that we can really help you to answer it specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a bit on how it's most convenient for you to sort the indexing, I think.. but here's an example, assuming your groups of start and end points are independently indexed 0-N..

[image]

- The curves are instanced on the start points, and their instance-indices captured
- After being *Realized*, the *Endpoint Selection* of the curves is moved to the 'end' group of points, keyed by the captured instance-index.

[image]

Comment: it perfectly works. thank you

Comment: it broke when I put a cut in the center of the mesh

Comment: the vertex group is doing weird stuff

Comment: this seems to be a problem with blender