# Reproducing the proportionally scaling inward and outward (Scale - Shift z) but using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

I'm trying to reproduce the proportionally scaling inward and outward (**Scale - Shift z**) or (<kbd>S</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) but using geometry nodes.

See image below of what I'm trying to get it to do.

[image: img1]

I tried this [Scaling only the selected vertex group in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266861/scaling-only-the-selected-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes)

But it doesn't seem to work in this case how can I fix this?

[image: img2]

**Pic of Gorgious suggestion:**

[image: img3]

Attached blend file below
[image]

Comment: You need to switch the Scale elements from Uniform to Axes and set to Z axis to 0

Comment: @Gorgious that didn't work I'll post a pic of what that does and post that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Transform Geometry` doesn't have a *Selection* socket, we need to use the `Scale Elements` node in *Single Axis* mode, as @Gorgious suggested. However, simply making the *Z* axis $0$ would result in a single direction of $(1,1,0)$ whereas we want to scale on *two* axes—$x(1,0,0)$ and $y(0,1,0)$—so we need to use two `Scale Elements` operations one after another for each of them:

[image]

By default, `Scale Elements` node scales each face or edge from their own individual 'origin's. To make them move together, we need to use a single *Center* as the operation origin—here I'm doing that by providing it with the selection's average position I get from an `Attribute Statistic` node.

***As a side note you're perhaps already aware:***

Why don't we use the three `Named Attribute`s as a selection directly, and first make it go through a `Capture Attribute` instead?

Because, it seems, domain interpolation going from vertices (*Point* domain) to faces have some differences between the old vertex group system (which is a special kind of float+boolean attribute field) and the new generic attributes system in *Geometry Nodes*. Directly using the vertex groups as a selection gives you extraneous faces (faces those vertices belong to) you don't want in your scaling operation. Capturing the vertex groups as a boolean field in the *Point* domain forces *Geometry Nodes* to re-do the interpolation, this time without those extraneous faces in our selection:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great!  Explanation!!!