# Enlarging hole in STL file

Tags: modeling, stl

I'm a complete beginner with blender and more familiar with Fusion 360 but it can't handle this large STL file, at least on my system. It just stops responding.

So the file is a full scale chest armor piece and I need to increase the neck hole size. The hole is an oval in the model. I not sure the best coarse of action here, any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks

[image: Chest armor]

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a boolean with a shape that represents the new, enlarged neck hole. This means that you need to model the new neck hole shape first. I think the best approach is to start with a cube.

1. Add a subdivision modifier to increase its resolution.
2. Crease the edges of the top and bottom faces to make it more a cylinder than a sphere.
3. Move the back face and scale it to get the desired shape.
4. Position and rotate the object to achieve the desired placement.

[image: Steps]

To perform the boolean, add a *Boolean* modifier to the armor and set the cube as the *Object*. Once you're happy with the result, apply the Boolean modifier. Make sure to hide the cube to see the result of the Boolean operation.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can select the inside faces to scale (increase hole)
2. S (Scale) - Shift-Z

[image: ani1]

Also [scaling-only-the-selected-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266861/scaling-only-the-selected-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes)

Comment: Except.. the little defects in the ref. image may indicate insanely high mesh density, and therefore, nowhere for the scaled geometry to go. You may be right, but my bet is that Boolean is the hack, and re-topology is the way :(